# Unintentionally bought 10kUSD of I bonds with a few cents: how can I correct my mistake and properly purchase 10kUSD of I bonds?

Tags: united-states, bonds, treasury

I bought 10kUSD of [I bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Savings_Bonds) via [treasurydirect.gov](https://treasurydirect.gov/). The bank account I mistakenly used to purchase the bonds only had a few cents. To my surprise, my account on [treasurydirect.gov](https://treasurydirect.gov/) indicates that the I bonds have been purchased:

[image]

The financial institution that manages the bank account I used, namely Fidelity, sent me a Direct Debit Failure Notification, understandably so.

How can I correct my mistake?

Comment: You'll probably want to reach out to TD and ask them?

Comment: I'm sure you're not the first to run into an overdraft bounce when trying to purchase bonds, by drawing from the wrong account or trying to use a deposit that hadn't yet fully been processed/confirmed or whatever.

Comment: @keshlam yes, that's why I'm asking the question here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Reddit user [DeluxeXL](https://www.reddit.com/user/DeluxeXL) [mentioned](https://redd.it/1akso64) the following:

> It takes a few more days for the failure notification to reach TD's system. Then they'll un-issue your bonds.

That was correct, I received an email from the Treasury on 2024-02-07 indicating that the purchase request has been canceled:

[image: We're sorry, but your purchase request or reinvestment IAAAC was canceled. While trying to collect payment from your bank, they returned our debit. Please check the Investor InBox section of your TreasuryDirect account for more detailed information.]

Answer (score 0):

The payment was cancelled. That probably means the transaction didn't go through. So you didn't buy; you tried to buy and failed.